# "UPDATE" could not be called as a function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

this is the update function

```
this.UPDATE = function()  {     
    this.vel.add(this.acc);     
    this.pos.add(this.vel);     
    this.acc.mult(0); 
    }
```

this is where it is called

```
function draw() {
    background(0);
    rocket.UPDATE();
    rocket.render();
}
```

the error in the non-p5.js console says that UPDATE is not a function

this is the whole code

```
function Rocket() {
    this.pos = createVector(width/2, height);
    this.vel = createVector(0, -1);
    this.acc = createVector();
    this.applyForce = function(force) {
        this.acc.add(force);
    }
}

this.UPDATE = function()  {
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.mult(0);
}

this.render = function(){
    push();
    translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    rotate(this.vel.heading()); 
    rectMode(CENTER);
    Rect(0,0, 50, 10);
    Pop();
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 300)
    rocket = new Rocket();
}
function draw() {
    background(0);
    rocket.UPDATE();
    rocket.render();
}
```

i was expecting a rectangle to start moving upwards from the bottom of the screen. i am following a coding challenge by the coding train to do this.

Comment: this.UPDATE does not appear to be part of Rocket hence your error. You really should look at proper ways of creating a class, this solution you have is not a best practice.

Comment: What will happen, if you you rename your method to "update"?

Comment: You can change this.update to "update" and your function should work. Its because update is not in the scope of rocket, that you are getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` and `render` must be set in the scope of `Rocket`, but not in the global scope:

```js
function Rocket() {
    this.pos = createVector(width/2, height);
    this.vel = createVector(0, -1);
    this.acc = createVector();
    this.applyForce = function(force) {
        this.acc.add(force);
    }
  
    this.UPDATE = function()  {
        this.vel.add(this.acc);
        this.pos.add(this.vel);
        this.acc.mult(0);
    }

    this.render = function(){
        push();
        translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        rotate(this.vel.heading()); 
        rectMode(CENTER);
        rect(0,0, 50, 10);
        pop();
    }
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 300)
    rocket = new Rocket();
}
function draw() {
    background(0);
    rocket.UPDATE();
    rocket.render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```